# jQuery Slider - How to add navigation buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I installed a Li jQuery Slider module on a website I'm working on and can't figure out how to add buttons that you can click on. I would like the user to be able to click on the button and be redirected to a page. Please let me know how to do this! Thanks.

Example:

[image]

Comment: If you mean "redirected to a URL" then have the button submit a form or change `window.location` when the button is clicked -- standard stuff. If you mean something else, clarify.

Comment: which slider you are using because by seeing the image no one can help you my dear. please provide some code/fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Li jQuery Slider is a image slider, so you have to add the button to your image.

If you want to have more than images in your slider, then you have to use anything slider or content slider, or one of the others, see [jQuery space saving content sliders and carousels](http://speckyboy.com/2011/07/15/15-jquery-space-saving-content-sliders-and-carousels/).

Comment: That's what I figured after looking at the code for a while... Thank you sir.